# Dump time and frequency in a sine wav into csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing

Am just plotting a sine wave and doing a plot spectrum analysis(similar to the one which is in audacity).

To plot i have a function like:

```
pxx, f, t, ax = plt.specgram(
    audio_data, NFFT=size, Fs=rate, noverlap=0, cmap=plt.cm.binary,
    sides='onesided', window=signal.hann(size), mode='magnitude')
plt.plot(f, 20 * np.log10(np.mean(pxx, axis=1)), 'b')
```

This function plots as expected. But i need to dump the frequency and time of the sine wave into the file in the below format.

```
Time(secs)    Freq
0.5           100
1             200
```

Is there a way to do this using the values returned in specgram.

Please note am pretty new to audio analysis am just learning my trade. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i would stuff your data in to a pandas DataFrame and use its `.to_csv` method

Comment: @PaulH Or, you know, not bother with Pandas for a trivial CSV dump and just use the built-in `csv` module instead.

Comment: Can you include the plot output image in your question?

Comment: @AKX for someone who's asking this kind of question, I think it's safe to say 1) they already have pandas, 2) there additional analysis to be done that pandas will facilitate, and 3) `pandas.DataFrame(dict_of_arrays).to_csv('output.csv)` is pretty dang "trivial"

Comment: @PaulH I wouldn't be that sure they already have Pandas. Either way, sorry, that was a little standoffish from me, it's just a bit of a pet peeve for me that it seems the Python side of SO these days doesn't know how to use Python at all without Pandas.

Comment: @AKX I think it's OK for some folks to focus on the science and pandas/scipy really enable that. It's also important in a scientific context to write code that fellow scientists can peer review and improve. It's great to have options.

Answer (score 1):

The Matplotlib `specgram` helper automatically segments your signal and runs FFT on it, so you end up with an image. That won't help you much for outputting text data.

In addition, at any given point in time multiple frequencies will exist in the signal (yes, even a monophonic sine wave due to FFT imprecision), so you can't describe a signal at any given time with just a single "Freq" value. You could, however, figure out a peak frequency for a time window.

You can find [the source for `specgram` here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/41482627d447e677fd9102e71d04dadaa7a179fe/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L703) if you feel like adapting it, but it might be better to [look at SciPy's FFT functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html) (or [this tutorial](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_fftpack.html)) so you get numeric data from the get-go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Assuming if i dont plot. just have a raw data read using scipy.io.read. Will that help me to acheive what i need. If yes can you let me know how ?

Comment: If you have a time-series signal you've read in with `scipy.io.read()`, then yeah, you can window and FFT it using the Scipy FFT functions.